# How to use vue.js with sails js

Tags: vue.js, sails.js, vuejs2, vue-component, sails.io.js

I want to use vue.js as frontend for sails.js i tried to configure using the method given at
http://filipbartus.name/integrate-vue-loader-with-sails-js/ but it was not working for vue latest version but i don't see any reason why? can someone explain why is it not working please?

latest version not working:  https://github.com/jeevansai502/kube

previous version from example working:  https://github.com/filipinyo/vue_sails_integration

Comment: Vue.js is extremely progressive. The most basic integration would consist of a simple script in your Sails layout to reference a CDN. But if you want to use vue-cli with the webpack template and vue-router, that's another story... This would conflict with the Sails workflow (which uses Grunt) and its internal routing. Anyway, you should provide more information in your question if you want to get a relevant answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think tha the best options is replacing Grunt with Webpack and vue loader.
Look at this repo https://github.com/Tarrask/sails-hook-webpack-vue. It's pretty easy with this hook.